# How to Remove items (Object) from an Array after comparing from 2nd array?

Tags: arrays, json, object, suitescript2.0

How can i remove the objects in My 1st Array which have `recordType` and `ids` matching with my `recordType` and `ids` of my 2nd Array.
Please help me I am stuck so bad.

My 1st Array:

```
 [
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "208336",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "141149",
          "text": "7457 abc company"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "582344",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "312",
          "text": "2001 efg Group"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "532294",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "133319",
          "text": "1356 xyz group -"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "139204",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "133319",
          "text": "2357 xyz group -"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "900994",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "133319",
          "text": "3357 ssf group -"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

My 2nd Array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "17271",
    "recordType": "CashSale"
  },
  {
    "id": "18469",
    "recordType": "CashSale"
  },
  {
    "id": "208336",
    "recordType": "CashSale"
  },
  {
    "id": "35406",
    "recordType": "CashSale"
  },
  {
    "id": "900994",
    "recordType": "CashSale"
  },
  {
    "id": "208336",
    "recordType": "CashSale"
  }
]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
My 1st Array without 1st and 2nd item removed.

```
[
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "582344",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "312",
          "text": "2001 efg Group"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "532294",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "133319",
          "text": "1356 xyz group -"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "recordType": "cashsale",
    "id": "139204",
    "values": {
      "entity": [
        {
          "value": "133319",
          "text": "2357 xyz group -"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A naive approach would just be doing a nested loop; the performance would be acceptable unless you are dealing with a lot of entries. You could use `filter` to simplify the code. It'd be something like this:

```
firstArray = firstArray.filter(x => {
    for (let y of secondArray) {
        if (x.id === y.id && x.recordType === y.recordType) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
)
```

Note that this comparison of recordtype is case-sensitive; I'm assuming your example is not deliberately ignoring case.

If you are dealing with large data sets, I would suggest using hash tables to reduce this from a `O(n^2)` process to a `O(n)` one.

Comment: simple! and the best. Thanks Richard! :)

Comment: i m sorry i mistakenly donwgraded it :(

Comment: Don't worry. It's fine.